# What is the best way to fillter null from a list in dart language

Tags: dart

Looking for a dart equivalent of python filter

```
a = ['', None,4]
[print(e) for e in filter(None,a)]
```

My code is too ugly:

```
List a = [null,2,null];
List b=new List();
for(var e in a){if(e==null) b.add(e);}
for(var e in b){a.remove(e);}
print(a);
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can use the List's `removeWhere` method like so:

```
List a = [null, 2, null];
a.removeWhere((value) => value == null);
print(a); // prints [2]
```

Answer (score 155):

in new dart 2.12 with sound null safety, the best way is:

```
List<int?> a = [null,2,null];
final List<int> b = a.whereType<int>().toList();
```

Comment: More clean with type checking

Comment: I wonder if reflection incurs some performance penalty vs the `removeWhere` solution.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for: converting from `List<Type?>` to `List<Type>`, simple cast won't work.

Comment: Nice! Odd that we can't do `.where((a) => a != null)`

Comment: Why is this the best way?

Comment: @DustinSilk, we can still do that.

Comment: @dan-gph That will remove the nulls, but the type of the list would still be `List<int?>`

Comment: How using `whereType` with `List a = [1,'a',null];`?
I think `whereType` does not work with this (I use `removeWhere` in this case). If this can work, tell me a solution, please.

Answer (score 62):

With **null-safety** the old *removeWhere* solution does no longer work, if the type of the resulting list is to be non-nullable. Casting after removeWhere doesn't work as well.

The best option is to import **collection**

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
```

which allows one to do

```dart
List<int> a = [null, 2, null].whereNotNull().toList();
print(a);
>>> [2]
```

Comment: I think this is by far the best solution because it's more obvious what's actually happening.

Comment: this `Collection` package is not stopping from how well it uses `extension methods` to add a simple methods to get stuff done really `powerfull`

Comment: @ABDERRAHMANEOUALI the biggest pain is that you have to import it manually everytime... But it's so useful

Comment: Another great feature of collection.dart is using the firstOrNull function. I use it all the time to produce better code.

Comment: This is my favorite solution because it can automatically cast List<String?> into List<String>

Answer (score 13):

```
  a.where((x) => x != null).forEach(print);
```

Answer (score 8):

In modern Dart you can use "collection if" and "collection for", which are similar to Python's list comprehensions:

```dart
List a = [null, 2, null];
List b = [for (var i in a) if (i != null) i];
print(b); // prints [2]
```

Source: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/accepted/2.3/control-flow-collections/feature-specification.md#composing

Answer (score 3):

I made an extension function with @Wesley Changs answer.

```
  extension ConvertIterable<T> on Iterable<T?> {
    List<T> toNonNullList() {
      return this.whereType<T>().toList();
    }
  }
```

You can use like below.

```
  List<int?> a = [null,2,null];
  final List<int> b = a.toNonNullList();
```

Answer (score 0):

To summarize and provide an **improved solution**, one could use extensions on `Iterable<E>` as expressed by @BansookNam's answer.

```dart
extension NotNullIterable<E> on Iterable<E?> {
  Iterable<E> whereNotNullable() => whereType<E>();
}
```

Sample usage

```
final nonNullList = [1, 2, 3, null, 4].whereNotNullable().toList();
```

A **better solution** for this problem is per @felix-ht's suggestion by making use of `package:collection/collection.dart`

Sample usage

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

//...

final nonNullList = [1, 2, 3, null, 4].whereNotNullable().toList();
```