# How to skip Null value from List<dynamic> in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

***Summary:***
I have a List of dynamic data such as {"CSE", "EEE", null, "ACCE"}.
Now I want to show these data through ListView builder except the null.
But I can't skip the null value. It gives:

`Exception has occurred. (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast)`

My code is given below and I tried other method too, which I give in the screenshots.

```
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors, prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables

import 'package:campuslib/controllers/content_controller.dart';
import 'package:campuslib/utils/colors.dart';
import 'package:campuslib/utils/dimensions.dart';
import 'package:campuslib/utils/routers.dart';
import 'package:campuslib/widgets/big_text.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class DepartmentBody extends StatefulWidget {
  const DepartmentBody({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DepartmentBody> createState() => _DepartmentBodyState();
}

class _DepartmentBodyState extends State<DepartmentBody> {
  final ContentController _contentController = Get.put(ContentController());

  late Map<String, String> deptFullName = {
    "cse": "Computer Science and Engineering",
    "eee": "Electrical and Electronic Engineering",
    "math": "Mathematics",
    "sta": "Statistics",
    "nonacademic": "Non Academic",
    "islamic": "Islamic",
    "acce": "Applied Chemistry & Chemical Engineering",
  };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(() {
      if (!(_contentController.dept.value.data != null)) {
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      } else {
        var deptList = _contentController.dept.value.data?.getDepartments;
        return _initDeptBody(deptList);
      }
    });
  }

  Widget _initDeptBody(var deptList) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          BigText(
            text: "Departments",
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            size: 20,
          ),
          Obx(() => (!_contentController.isLoadingForDept.value)
              ? Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(40),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(40),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: deptList?.length,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                          _buildDepartmentItem(deptList, index),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              : CircularProgressIndicator())
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildDepartmentItem(var deptList, int index) {
    final String? currentString = deptList[index];
    if (currentString != null) {
      return Container(
        height: Dimension.deptNameContainer(context),
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 20),
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
          child: Stack(
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    image: AssetImage("assets/images/${deptList[index]}.jpg"),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Card(
                elevation: 0.0,
                margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                color: Color.fromARGB(202, 25, 24, 24),
                child: Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      // Navigator.name(context, MyRouters.departmentRoute);
                      Get.toNamed(MyRouters.departmentRoute, arguments: {
                        "deptBanner": deptList[index],
                        "deptName": deptFullName[deptList[index]],
                      });
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        ListTile(
                          title: Text(
                            deptFullName[deptList?[index]]!,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: AppColors.lightColor,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              // fontSize: 18,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return Container();
    }
  }
}
```

***Screenshots:***

[image]

**Flutter doctor:**
[image: Flutter doctor]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to fillter null from a list in dart language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513924/what-is-the-best-way-to-fillter-null-from-a-list-in-dart-language)

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the null value to cast them in the list like

`List<String> validDeptList = deptList?.where((dept) => dept != null).toList() ?? [];`

In this form, validDeptList have only non-null values.